# DTFT and Eigenvalues in frequency domain

Tags: frequency, frequency-response, dtft

Consider an LTI system with impulse response $h[k]$. Does the frequency response $H(e^{j\Omega})$ equal the eigenvalue corresponding to an eigensignal of frequency $\Omega$?

So if I convolve an eigensignal $x[k]$ of the system with the impulse response $h[k]$, I get the $H(e^{j\Omega})$ (=Eigenvalue?) scaled eigensignal $x[k]$ as output $y[k]$, what does this mean for frequency response plots?

[image]

Does this mean, that graphs of the frequency response just show where the eigenvalues lay?

Say I have a maximum at $\Omega = 0$ with value 3 and one at $\Omega = \pi$ with value 2, are 3 and 2 eigenvalues of the system?
Because the magnitude of the eigensignals itself should always be 1, it just gets scaled by the eigenvalue (=$H(e^{j\Omega})$).
So are frequency response plots just basically "eigenvalue over frequency" plots? This seems to be the case.

Does this sentence hold true in general and for all (LTI) systems?
Is the frequency response always "eigenvalues of a system over frequency"?

Comment: Could you please define (1) eigenvalue of a signal; and (2) eigensignal?

Comment: An eigensignal was defined in the lecture as a signal x[k] as input convolved with the impulse response gives a signal y[k] = a x[k] as output, with a as arbitrary constant. But now when i think about it, shouldnt a be the eigenvalue?

Comment: OK, so just to clarify, the terminology comes from linear algebra. If you have a matrix $A$, vector $x \neq 0$, and scalar $\lambda$, then if $Ax=\lambda x$, $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ and $\lambda$ is the associated eigenvalue. **Important:** $x$ is not an eigenvector by itself; it is an eigenvector of $A$. Likewise, _systems_ have eigensignals; if $x(t) \ast h(t) = \lambda x(t)$, then $x(t)$ is an eigensignal **of the system** $h(t)$, and $\lambda$ is the associated eigenvalue. It does not make sense to say "$x(t)$ is an eigensignal" without specifying the system it is an eigensignal of.

Comment: Given this standard terminology, please edit your question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: Thank you, I (and someone else, thx) edited the question

Comment: Sorry, but I still couldn't get past the first sentence; I have edited it.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong in your understanding. An LTI system has an infinite of eigensignals. The frequency response plot is essentially a plot of the eigenvalues for each frequency. Don't forget that the frequency response can affect both the amplitude and the phase, though.

Comment: Thanks! I think thats a very interesting sentence that should be said in the lectures when introducing frequency responses. So they are basically plots of the eigenvalues for each frequency. Does this sentence hold true for frequency responses with inputs other than the eigensignal though? This would mean that a frequency response is not always the eigenvalue over frequency. When would I use the eigensignal as input?

Comment: It is only true for eigensignals (that is, for complex exponentials). However, Fourier tells us that every signal is a sum of complex exponentials, so the frequency response gives you the system's response to any input (here I'm sweeping some mathematical technicalities under the rug).

Comment: That reads a bit like "yes, but no". So, is the frequency response plot (in general and always, for all systems) the plot of eigenvalues of the system over frequency? If the answer is yes, I dont have any questions anymore, for now. If the answer is no, I might have an existential crisis.

Comment: The answer is yes, as long as the system is LTI.

Comment: <<<<Thank you!>>>>